# Copy Woocommerce product short description to ACF

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I want to copy the `short description` of all the products to an acf custom field that i created. The custom field's name is `sxolia` . I don't know how can i catch this ACF Field with a query to the database.

```
UPDATE `wp_posts`
SET `post_excerpt` = `?`
WHERE `post_type` = 'product'
AND `post_status` = 'publish'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ACF function `update_field($selector, $value, $post_id);` to set the value of a specific field.

More info here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/